# Comparação mesmo periodo do mês passado SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Preciso fazer uma query que traga a quantidade de ordens do mesmo período do mês anterior. Porém, a comparação é o seguinte: se hoje é dia 3 de abril, preciso trazer dia 1, 2 e 3 de março.
Se hoje é dia 10 de abril, preciso trazer o os primeiros 10 dias de março também e assim sucessivamente.

```
select count(distinct idt_ordens), dat_creation
from tabela
where dat_creation  >= date_trunc('day', current_date) - interval '1' month
group by dat_creation
```

Comment: Informe o SGBD (banco) pois a solução pode depender deste , em tese eu faria duas tabelas virtuais (até views) com "running totals" e depois comparando via lead / lag , usando analytic (window) functions . Mas publique a estrutura da tabelas e um exemplo de como precisa da saída , se possível um exemplo no sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando a sintaxe de uso do [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) e a função [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), usadas na sql apresentada:

```
select count(distinct idt_ordens), dat_creation
from tabela
where dat_creation  >= date_trunc('day', current_date) - interval '1' month
group by dat_creation
```

Cabe uma resposta para usuários do [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/), que também atende ao autor da pergunta, mesmo não tendo sido informado o SBGD (sistema gerenciador de banco de dados).

O trecho `date_trunc('day', current_date) - interval '1' month` consegue definir adequadamente o equivalente ao mesmo dia no mês anterior, ao truncar tudo que vier depois do dia e subtrair um mês da data após truncar, não importando se o mês tem 28 ou 31 dias.

Fica faltando definir o primeiro dia do mês anterior, para validar o período que se deseja, usando `(date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1' month)`, que trunca tudo que vier depois do mês e joga para o dia 1 e subtrai um mês após truncar.

Após definir as condições de selecionar as informações, só usar na consulta:

```
select count(distinct idt_ordens), dat_creation
from tabela
-- maior ou igual ao primeiro dia do mês anterior
where dat_creation >= (date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1' month)
    -- menor ou igual ao dia equivalente do mês anterior
    and dat_creation <= (date_trunc('day', current_date) - interval '1' month)
group by dat_creation
```

Particularmente prefiro a sintaxe utilizando [between](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) para intervalos.

```
select count(distinct idt_ordens), dat_creation
from tabela
where dat_creation between (date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1' month)
    and (date_trunc('day', current_date) - interval '1' month)
group by dat_creation
```

Veja a definição das datas funcionando: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ar0xijFC);

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ainda bem que ajudou, qual o banco de dados que você está usando?

Comment: Banco de dados postgres amigo